# Xcode 4.1 Archive Build in organizer doesn't show icon

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4, app-store-connect

My application icon's work fine when displaying on iPad and iPhone, however after I build for archive, and create the archive, there is no icon shown. Any ideas? I've looked around at several forums and haven't found a resolution. I actually don't believe this has any effect on the actual distribution deployment, as the .ipa definitely has the icons bundled with it. I've loaded it directly into iTunes to verify that.

See screenshots below, I already have "Icon File" (CFBundleIconFile) and "Icon Files" (CFBundleIconFiles) defined.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question, though a light bulb just went off in my head. Within Xcode 4 organizer archives, applications are grouped. As in if you archive 5 versions, you select the application on the left pane, and than the 5 versions show on the right pane. This lead me to believe that it's not actually the application icons that are used to show the grouped application on the left pane, but the actual iTunesArtwork file. So I added it to the CFBundleIconFiles collection, and it worked!

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's a side effect to this. Under products, the [AppName].app file icon now doesn't show now. However, the app compiles and runs fine. I don't believe any of Apple's documentation says anything about adding iTunesArtwork to the CFBundleIconFiles array, so for now I'll leave it out and assume this is an Xcode/archive bug.

Comment: I started getting this problem with Xcode 4.3, and adding the iTunesArtwork entry to CFBundleIconFiles solved the problem, without the side effect you mention above. So far so good.

Comment: Although the documentation has not been updated for iOS 5, I quote that in the following link Apple specifically says that "Except for iTunesArtWork icon, list the names of each of these files in the Icon files entry in the Info.plist."   http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html   I have also run into this problem, and it seems that previously the Organiser would not only show artwork, it would use the iTunesArtwork which shows up beautifully, now I've got it to show the icon, but it's ugly and blown up, we should assume this is an Xcode bug for now.

Comment: I mentioned iOS 5 because now there are two properties in the info.plist for icon files, there is "Icon files" and the new "Icon files (iOS 5)" which I've only noticed recently, there is no mention about the latter on Apple documentation other then the fact you can specifically supply newsstand icons in there along side primary icons.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because you don't have the 512x512 iTunesArtwork file.

[image]

Comment: Yes that's correct. This question is getting dated. The documentation on the iOS developer site was lacking at the time of the original question.

Comment: @mservidio fair enough. hope it may help for others then.

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty entry for `CFBundleIconFile`. If you remove it completely it *should* work.

Icon handling in the Xcode Organizer has been a bit buggy in the past, so I wouldn't put too much stock in it. Just make sure the icons are displaying correctly on the actual platforms you intend to ship on.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried that already, just tried it again also. No luck...

Comment: Like you say, it's been buggy in the past, I think I saw this with Xcode 3.x at some point. Though I've never had a problem deploying into to the store.