# Icon not showing in xcode organizer

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode4.5, archive, organizer

Referencing question [Xcode 4.1 Archive Build in organizer doesn't show icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808357/xcode-4-1-archive-build-in-organizer-doesnt-show-icon). I'm using xcode 4.5 (IOS6)

I am running into the issue where I've tried every SO answer I could find in regards to this and it still isn't working. So ya I'm just about upload to the app store and I got to the point in http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2 where it's time to archive. I go to archive and in the organizer my icon is blank! No question mark or anything, just blank.

What I've tried:
Adding all relevant Icon files to plist (Icon.png, Icon@2x.png, iTunesArtwork)
Tried it in keys Icon Files, Icon Files (IOS5), Icon File all together and separately as well. 
Tried moving the files around between the supporting files folder and the root (no more resources folder)

I've ran out of ideas! Does this step matter that much? I mean the icon shows on the phone and of course the app store setup as well. Anyway all help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents: if you see it showing up on the phone and are sure you added all the icon/artwork files in there, you probably have nothing to worry about.

Optionally, you could see what results you get with the Xcode->Organizer->Archives->YourApp-> "Validate" button,

or

You might try submitting it to the app store with the "Wait-until-I-tell-you-to-publish-it" (paraphrased) option checked, and see what it looks like in your itunes connect account. If you see the icons/artwork there and all looks dandy, you should be good to go. That way if anything looks funny, you can resubmit the icons ( I believe you can just do that as meta-data and not an entire binary ) before it goes live.

As a side note, I'm fairly positive iTunes would most likely reject and not publish an app that contained no icons/artwork.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Miles. Validation went through well and all files are added. I took the leap of faith and pressed the go button! I guess one can only wait now. I figured with all the pics they have you upload for their end and the fact that it's visible on the phone from my end as you should keep me in good shape. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Just confirming the previous answerer's hypothesis: Despite the fact that I added all the icon files to my XCode project, when I archived the application, the icon did not show up in the Organizer. I submitted the binary anyway, and it was accepted - it must have been an XCode error, but it's no big deal!